# Initialization of a local static variable throught multiple function calls

Tags: c++

```
int f(int &g){
    static int a=g;
    a+=1;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int g=0;
    int a=f(g);
    g=10;
    a=f(g);
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code gives output 2. 
What my guess was that it should be 11.

I do understand that the `a` in main function is not the same as that in f function. So when `g=0`, a in f would be 1, I believe. Then when `g=10`, it should be 11, giving `a=11` in main. Why isn't that the case? Thanks!

Comment: `a` is static so there's only one instance of it and `static int a=g;` initialises `a`, which is something that can only happen once throughout the lifetime of a program, you'd see different results if you assigned it without initialising,  `static int a; a = g;`

Comment: @user11067275 First of all, c++ isn't a _scripting language_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the `static` keyword here. When a local variable is declared `static`, it is initialized once. Inside of the function, this is when then function is called the first time. You first call this function in

```
int g=0;
int a=f(g);
```

The local variable `a` inside `f` is hence initialized to zero and then incremented. Later on, you call `f` a second time,

```
g=10;
a=f(g);
```

but as the local variable is already initialized, it is not overwritten. Instead, the second increment takes place, resulting in the value of `2`.